# jQuery submit(), change() and page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, onchange

I'm trying to submit form on select change. Without page refreshing.

Example 1:

```
<form>
    <select>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

.

```
$('select').change(function() {
        console.log('changed');
        this.form.submit(function (e) {
                alert('form submitted');
                e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ty8Lrdm0/

**Question:** Why `form` still refreshing the page on submit?

Example 2:

```
<form id="form">
    <select>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

.

```
$('select').change(function() {
        console.log('changed');
        $('#form').submit(function (e) {
                alert('form submitted');
                e.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wsjLx1cs/2/

**Question:** Why this example does not work?

Comment: Because you have the button type as submit. just remove the type and you should be good

Comment: Now in your second fiddle you didn't load jQuery at all. Load jQuery and it will work.

Comment: To submit form data without refreshing page you need to use AJAX

Comment: @Franco Nope https://jsfiddle.net/wsjLx1cs/2/

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but the fiddle has your own code. You say you want submit only after the user has made a selection and this is just what your second fiddle does when I try it..

Comment: @Yuri Here's example with ajax https://jsfiddle.net/wsjLx1cs/3/

Comment: @Franco i need to stop form refreshing page on submit. Submit() `form` on `select` Change() without page reload.

Comment: If you keep on changing the fiddle you need to mention this in your answer and put the link there and NOT in the comments. Placing the changes in the comments will make all the previous posted answers incorrect or obsolete.

Comment: Besides you have many error in your ajax call code which needs to be corrected before attempting to let it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to submit form on select change. Without page refreshing.

You should be looking at AJAX method for doing a partial refresh.

You can bind the event handler for change and rather than trying to submit the form do an AJAX request, handle the request in the server and pass the response back to the client.

***Issue with your second piece of code***

You are trying to hook a submit event handler to the form, so everytime the form gets submitted this event will be invoked before that.

If you want a submission to happen it should be

```
$("#formid").submit();
```

But in this case the entire page will get refreshed.

Read more on jQuery ajax event in **[`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

Answer (score 2):

In the first case

```
this.form.submit(function (e) {
          alert('form submitted');
          e.preventDefault();
     });
```

`this` is the dom object not jQuery object, so your calling `submit()` on the form which submits the form.

In the second case

```
$('#form').submit(function (e) {
             alert('form submitted');
            e.preventDefault();
     });
```

you are assigning a submit event handler to the form not triggering it.